# Reading data from a json using Python and using it to draw shapes

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, scikit-image, coco

I have a COCO formatted json which if you are not familiar with COCO, is just a list of coordinates of 10 sided polygons (attached an example).

I need to create an array from these coordinates that will plot them on a 128 x 128 square as filled in polygons so that I can multiply it with another array.

I have so far tried skimage.draw polygons and matplotlib polygons.
These work if I manually enter coordinates, but I don't know how to read the data in from the json and then use that as the coordinates.

Below is an example of the json.

```
{
"version": "4.6.0",
"flags": {},
"shapes": [
{
  "label": "blob",
  "points": [
    [
      75.14285714285714,
      83.71428571428571
    ],
    [
      72.23121416791264,
      82.67540136440437
    ],
    [
      70.48628641932781,
      80.12350546954684
    ],
    [
      70.57457698914924,
      77.03333552579737
    ],
    [
      72.46236188059122,
      74.58523142065489
    ],
    [
      75.42857142857144,
      73.71428571428571
    ],
    [
      78.34021440351594,
      74.75317006416705
    ],
    [
      80.08514215210077,
      77.30506595902457
    ],
    [
      79.99685158227935,
      80.39523590277405
    ],
    [
      78.10906669083737,
      82.84334000791652
    ]
  ],
  "group_id": null,
  "shape_type": "polygon",
  "flags": {}
```

I have tried:

```
f=open('139cm_2000_frame27.json') 
data=json.load(f) 
shapes=data["shapes"] 
for i in shapes: 
    print('points')
```

but it errors at 'points'
Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is your code which parses this json? Did you find out how to access values from a dict?

Comment: Im not sure how to access an array in an object in an object?

Comment: Sorry, but stackoverflow is not a software development environment. It is a forum to answer very specific questions in order to leave a trail of solutions for all future programmers to follow. Please don't wipe out your original question only to replace it with a new one.

Comment: Sorry !! I really didn't know, truly. This is my first time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library to work with *json* objects. If you need to load the json from a file use `json.load()` like so:

```py
import json
with open('example.json', 'r') as f:
    versions = json.load(f)['versions']
```

and use loads when from a string:

```py
import json
json_str = '{"versions": 10}'
versions = json.loads(json_str)['versions']
```

Comment: Okay, so say I only wanted the points for each 'i' in shapes, how would I do that? I cant work out how to access an array stored in an object stored in an array? I tried: 
    f=open('139cm_2000_frame27.json')
    data=json.load(f)
    shapes=data["shapes"]   

    for i in shapes:
        print('points')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you’ve managed to get some way. You now have to navigate the ‘dicts within lists within dicts’. This code will simply print out all the coordinates of all the shapes:

```py
f=open('139cm_2000_frame27.json') 
data=json.load(f) 
shapes=data["shapes"] 
for i in shapes: 
    print(i['label'])   # prints the label first
    for c in i['points']:
        print(c)       # a list containing coordinates
```

Comment: Thats perfect thank you. It now prints all the coordinates, do you know how I can store all of what it prints in a variable? I need to use the first 10 coordinates to draw a 10 sided polygon, then the next 10 coordinates to draw another 10 sided polygon etc.... on a 128x128 array

Comment: I think that needs a new question. You need to be very specific about the `"first 10 coordinates"` thing. How many coordinates do you expect to find in the `i['points']` list and what to do when there are more or less than 10 coordinates. Also, how many `shapes` are there? Should the coordinates for those be kept separate from other shapes?

Answer (score 0):

I would have chosen jmespath libray for this use case to extract points from the json
`pip install jmespath` just check it out

```
#we are searching in shapes list and fetching out label and points from it it will give us list of dictionary for each shapes
import jmespath
expression = jmespath.compile('shapes[*].{Name: label, points: points}')
for shape_name,points in expression.search(data)[0].items():
    print(shape_name, points)
```